# PrimeFaces openDialog not working properly within nested dialogs

Tags: primefaces, dialog, nested

I’m using PrimeFaces 6.0 and I’ve found a problem using nested dialogs. **RequestContext.openDialog** is not working properly. It doesn’t throw any exception, but it doesn’t open the dialog.

I built 5 pages (P1 to P5) based on the same Full Page Layout. Each page contains a **p:dataTable**. The **p:dataTable** has a **p:column** with a **p:commandButton** to open the next page in a new dialog. This is what I’ve found: on some of those pages the button of the first row doesn’t work; the buttons of the rest of the rows work properly.

The problem doesn’t seem to be inherent to the row data. When the button of the first row fails, it fails regardless the row that is being showed there. Rows can be sorted in different ways (so the first one would vary) and the button of the first row will continue failing and the rest of the buttons will continue working. The problem doesn’t seem to be inherent to the page either. All buttons work properly when the page is root (the one that opens the first dialog). The problem only happens within a dialog.

This is the button:

```
<p:commandButton
    icon="fa fa-folder-open"
    action="#{ambientePrueba11.openDialog(currentRow)}"
    partialSubmit="true"
    process="@this"
    update="@none">
    <p:ajax
        event="dialogReturn"
        listener="#{ambientePrueba11.onDialogReturn}"
        update="dataTable"/>
</p:commandButton>
```

This is the code in the backing bean (each of the 5 beans have a different outcome, but the rest of the code is the same):

```
public String openDialog(AmbientePrueba row) {
    EventLogger.log(this, "openDialog", getDenominacion(row));
    Object identificacion = getIdentificacion(row);
    String key = "PaquetePrueba11";
    String outcome = FacesUtils.getPageKeyFacesOutcome(key);
    Map<String, Object> options = new HashMap<>();
    options.put("modal", true);
    options.put("resizable", true);
    options.put("draggable", true);
    options.put("width", 1260);
    options.put("height", 860);
    options.put("contentWidth", "100%");
    options.put("contentHeight", "100%");
    options.put("closable", true);
    options.put("includeViewParams", true);
    options.put("minimizable", true);
    options.put("maximizable", true);
    Map<String, List<String>> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put(CPP.ID_RECURSO, toList(identificacion));
    params.put(CPP.ID_RECURSO_MAESTRO, toList(identificacion));
    params.put(Global.PARAMETRO_FRAMEWORK_SESION, toList(getSessionFrame()));
    params.put(Global.PARAMETRO_CONDICION_SESION, toList(MODAL));
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().openDialog(outcome, options, params);
    return null;
}
private List<String> toList(Object value) {
    List<String> paramValue = new ArrayList<>();
    paramValue.add(value + "");
    return paramValue;
}
public void onDialogReturn(SelectEvent event) {
    Object response = event.getObject();
    facesLogger.info(response + "");
}
```

Has anybody else found a similar problem? Any help to solve or workaround this problem will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Any Javascript error?

Answer (score 0):

After some more tests I found a work around. I just gave the button a different **id** in each page and now all the buttons of all the pages work just fine.

Now the button of page P1 (as its **id** suggests) looks like this:

```
<p:commandButton
    id=buttonOfPage1
    icon="fa fa-folder-open"
    action="#{ambientePrueba11.openDialog(currentRow)}"
    partialSubmit="true"
    process="@this"
    update="@none">
    <p:ajax
        event="dialogReturn"
        listener="#{ambientePrueba11.onDialogReturn}"
        update="dataTable"/>
</p:commandButton>
```